# Cloth Simulation with belt Question

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, cloth-simulation

So I made a rope on my character using the cloth Simulation and I wanted to put a belt around it. Is there a way I can do this after the simulation? (And I don't know that much of Blender so pictures or small tutorials would be nice)

Comment: Do you need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFFIh.gif)?

Comment: Do you mean *robe* on your character? That would seem to make more sense. Can you provide images of what you’ve currently got and describe how you’d like to add the belt? It’s very likely that you’ll have to re-run the simulation since the belt will directly affect the motion of the cloth and how it behaves.